# jade form that contains Vertical Tabs has to be converted into SideNav

Tags: angularjs, pug

the last few lines of JADE  contains md-tabs , these tabs should get converted to sidenav tabs. with only css change can we convert to sidenav ?

```
extends ../../../core/pronghorn/views/layout

block append scripts
    script(src="./scripts/angular-filter.min.js")
    script(src="./scripts/networkconfig.js")


block append links
    link(rel="stylesheet" href="../networkmanagement/style/networkStyle.css")

block append content    
    div(ng-controller="networkconfig" flex ng-cloak style="font-size:12px;ovelrflow-x:none" )
        //content layout start here
        div.layout-bg(layout="row" layout-fill="layout-fill" flex="flex" style="height:calc(100% - 10px); height:calc(100vh - 50px);")

            //Content - Right Section
            md-content.flex(layout="column"  )
                div.view-details-bar(layout='row' )
                    h3(style="height:35px;margin-left:38%;font-weight:bold") Network Inventory Management 
                    span(flex)
                    md-button(class="md-icon-button" ng-click="" help-window style="float:right")


                // Help content box 
                div( class="help-con-box" ng-if="showHelpCont" ) 
                    md-dialog-actions(layout="row" class="layout-row" style="min-height:30px; background-color:#fff" )
                        label() Steps to do... 
                        span(flex)
                        md-button.scrunched(class="md-icon-button" ng-click="hideHelpCont()" )

                    div(layout="row")            


                div.view-content( flex style="border-top:1px solid #ccc;height:calc(100% - 10px); height:calc(100vh - 50px);")

                     md-tabs(md-stretch-tabs style="padding:5px"   md-border-bottom md-dynamic-height )
                        //Network Inventory tab
                        md-tab(label="PNF/VNF Management")
                            include pnf_vnf_management.jade                                 
                        md-tab(label="Zone Management")
                            include zone_management.jade
                        md-tab(label="NTC Management" md-on-select="getNtcNames()")
                            include ntc_management.jade
```

Comment: css :  // this is the CSS of the code 
 
        md-content md-tabs md-tabs-canvas {background: #e5e5e5 !important;}
        md-tabs .md-tab.md-active, .md-tab.md-focused { color: #0679B4 !important;}
        md-tabs md-ink-bar { background: #0679B4 !important;}
        #my-button .md-button:hover, .md-button:focus { background-color: #f0f0f0 !important; color:#0679B4;
            /*height:35px;*/
        }